# How best to make a web app with multiple pages?

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, cordova, web

I'm trying to make a multiplatform offline webapp using PhoneGap. I know my html and css, but I'm not altogether familiar with the full capabilities of JavaScript, and I've never made a webapp before, let alone tried to use phonegap to empower it.

Right now, I have the main index.html that phonegap sets up for you, but now I'm uncertain as to how to proceed. If I want a button to take the user to another page from the main page, should I make a second html file and literally link between them, or is this a lot more complex than that?

Also (get ready for a possibly epically stupid question from a total beginner):

Do web apps have to be online? I'm really not clear on whether they function like normal websites in which they need to be hosted on a server, or if they can be packaged up and downloaded just like normal native apps. Please help!

Thanks.

Oh, and btw, I'm working in Xcode with the phonegap addon thing....I'm trying to get it running on the iphone before I move on to android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the other answer helped me at the time, I thought I would add a more complete answer now, five years later, to my own first StackOverflow question.

To start with, a "web app" is the same as a "website" in a technical sense, and yes, they have to be hosted on a server in order to be accessed through the browser...just like every website. The only distinction is that a web app is generally a more dynamic and complex sort of website, involving JavaScript and AJAX. It would be misleading to call a simple website like [this one](https://www.warnerbros.com/archive/spacejam/movie/jam.htm) a "web app," whereas Facebook is definitely a web app. Basically all web apps are websites, but not all websites are quite exactly web apps.

However, it only has to be "online" if you want it to be accessible anywhere from a browser via `http`. If you're making a Cordova app like I was at the time, that's not relevant. If you only want to run an application locally, you can do so with a local server like Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` or the one webpack provides, or any other alternative, including a server you write yourself from scratch.

As for the primary question about having multiple pages, yes anchor elements like `<a href="www.google.com">my link</a>` are the standard way of connecting pages. To link among your own pages, you would have multiple .html files, and you would create a link with an href like `href="myOtherPage.html"`, where that file is contained in the same directory as the file for the page linking to it. Alternatively you could set up a single-page-app where JavaScript loads new page content without the use of anchor elements-- in that case multiple .html files are not needed. Frameworks like Angular and React are helpful for accomplishing that, but it's by no means necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical web app, most of the time you would just need to create a link as you would if you were creating a link on a website. Also, Web apps can be developed via a local environment (research Mamp/ or Wamp) depending on the dependencies in which your app require.